# Rails array association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have an association in rails between 3 models

```
class A < ApplicationController
  has_many :b
end


class B < ApplicationController
  has_many :c
  belongs_to :a
end


class C < ApplicationController
  belongs_to :b
end
```

when I write in the terminal:

```
A.first.b.first.c
```

works perfectly

but when I write

```
A.first.b.c
A.first.b.all.c
```

then rails return array []

how can I get all the c models associated to A.first but withouth use trough in the associations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map`:

```
A.first.b.map(&:c)
```